# Passar valores página Aspx para Aspx.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Tenho uma página Aspx o seguinte código que carrega uma lista de itens. Está funcionando, a lista é exibida normalmente.

```
<table width="100%" class="table table-striped">
<tr>
<th>Id</th>
<th>Nome</th>
<th>CPF</th>
<th>E-mail</th>
<th>Adicionar Telefone</th>
<th>Editar | Deletar</th>
</tr>
<% foreach (var item in pessoaList) { %>
<tr>
<td><%= item.id %></td>
<td><%= item.nome %></td>
<td><%= item.cpf %></td>
<td><%= item.email %></td>
<td><!-- Código Modal --></td>

<td>
<asp:Button ID="EditarPessoaButton" cssClass="btn btn-info" runat="server" CommandName="EditarPessoa" Text="Editar" ValidationGroup="EditarPessoa" onclick="EditarPessoaButton_Click"/>
<asp:Button ID="ExcluirPessoaButton" cssClass="btn btn-danger" runat="server" CommandName="ExcluirPessoa" Text="Excluir" ValidationGroup="ExcluirPessoa" onclick="ExcluirPessoaButton_Click"/>
</td>
</tr>
<% } %>
</table>
```

Pretendo passar o valor do `<%= item.id %>` por linha a linha da tabela como parâmetro para excluir e editar dados. Tentei usar o componente asp Textbox para guardar os valores porém sem sucesso. Preciso do valor `<%= item.id %>` no aspx.cs. Como passar o valor linha a linha do `<%= item.id %>` para a layer aspx.cs?

[Edit] Obs.: Gostaria de passar todos os valores dos item entre as Taglibs para formato de texto para poder manipulá=los. Componente asp Textbox fala que não é suportado quando adicionado entre as tags `<td></td>` e também gera erro em tempo de execução.

[Edit2] Segue resolução com GridView

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"     Width="100%" OnRowCommand="GV_RowCommand" AllowSorting="True"     DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowPaging="True" DataKeyNames="id" class="table     table-striped" style="border-color:transparent; color:black;">
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="ID" DataField="id"     SortExpression="id" Visible="false"></asp:BoundField>

<asp:TemplateField Visible="False">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox Text=<%# Eval("id")%> ID="txtIdPessoa" runat="server"     visible="false"/>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:BoundField HeaderText="NOME" DataField="nome"
SortExpression="nome"></asp:BoundField>

<asp:BoundField HeaderText="CPF" DataField="cpf"
SortExpression="cpf"></asp:BoundField>

<asp:BoundField HeaderText="E-MAIL" DataField="email"
SortExpression="email"></asp:BoundField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TELEFONE">
<ItemTemplate>
<!-- Codigo Modal -->
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="EDITAR | EXCLUIR">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Button Text="Editar" cssClass="btn btn-info" ID="btnUpdPessoa"     runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="EditarPessoaButton_Click"     CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id")%>' />                               
<asp:Button Text="Excluir" cssClass="btn btn-danger" ID="btnDelPessoa"     runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="ExcluirPessoaButton_Click"     CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id")%>'/>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ItauDAL %>"
SelectCommand="select * from Pessoa"
UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Pessoa] SET [nome] = @nome , [cpf] =  @cpf , [email]     = @email 
WHERE [id] = @id" >
<UpdateParameters>
<asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="nome"></asp:Parameter>
<asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="cpf"></asp:Parameter>
<asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="email"></asp:Parameter>
</UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1):

Como você está trabalhando com webforms, o mais indicado seria usar um componente como o GridView, que já possui eventos que facilitam esse trabalho.

No mais, caso prefira manter a atual estrutura, a única forma que conheço de passar dados de uma página .aspx para o seu respectivo code-behind é através do componente HiddenField.